# ASP: Assign a Gridview Value to a label

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i assign a value in the Gridview to a label?

```
Dim Command3 As New SqlCommand
            Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select [Parking_Cost] FROM Parking Where [Parking_ID] = @Parking_ID2", myConn)
            Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parking_ID2", Parking_ID2)

            Adapter.Fill(Dataset)
            Total.DataSource = Dataset
            Label14.DataBind()
            Total.DataBind()
```

Tried binding did not work

Any ideas?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. If there's only one `Datatable` in your `Dataset` then table index is 0.

```
label14.text = Datatset.Tables(table index).Rows.Item(row index)(column index).ToString
```

Comment: what is table index and row index ?

Comment: @Humam Shbib Table index is the index of the table in your dataset, if only one table the index is 0. Row index is the index of the row you want your data from. If there is only one row it would be 0. Column index is the index of the column your data is in, again it is zero based, so if there is only one column it would be 0.